# What does one call this diagram of flow of development tools? How does one decide what the best design is for their development needs?

Tags: angular, web, mariadb

First, [here is the diagram](https://youtu.be/pGYAg7TMmp0?t=2m32s), similar diagrams can be found at many more points in the video.

What does one call this diagram?

I'm interested in making my own version of this to have a clear flow to my project, but I'm  not sure what this is called or how to research it.  Because I'm not sure what to search for, searching for this topic has not been successful.

Additionally, what might be the best way to go about designing my own version of this diagram to suit my needs?  My main tools so far are Angular, MariaDB, Git (through GitHub), and I might introduce Docker soon.

Also, is this something taught in a typical Computer Science course?  I am a university student developing this website in my spare time, but I am not studying Computer Science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, here is the diagram, similar diagrams can be found at many more points in the video.

It looks like a [deployment diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram)

> Also, is this something taught in a typical Computer Science course? I
>   am a university student developing this website in my spare time, but
>   I am not studying Computer Science.

Yes, [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) is mostly part of a Computer Science study.